# Cyclic subgroups of $G$ with same order share only $1_G$

Tags: group-theory

I would like to prove that

> If $G$ is a group and $\langle a\rangle$, $\langle b\rangle$ are
>   distinct subgroups with the same order $n$, then $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle = \{1_G\}.$

I would write some results, but aren't interesting. I would thank a hint.

**Edit**: as shown by @bof, this isn't true in general, so I would like to prove it for $n$ prime.

Comment: What do u mean by `distinct`? Do u mean `non-isomorphic?` For example one of them is `abelian` and the other is `non-abelian`?

Comment: @B.S. I thought it was clear that both are subgroups of the same subgroup, distinct is that they have not both the same elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $G=S_7,\ a=(1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5),b=(1\ 2\ 3)(6\ 7)$?

It's true if $n$ is prime. Hint: in a group of prime order, every element except the identity generates the whole group.

Comment: Thanks. Great counterexample. When $n$ is prime then the proposition is true, right?

Comment: $\mathrm{ord}(\langle a \rangle \cap \langle b\rangle) \mid n$ prime so it is trivial or $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b\rangle$ are equal. Thanks